# instance down before kinesis putRecords api flush to stream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am going through the documentation of `Amazon Kinesis` and I found that using KPL will do all failover scenarios raised with Kinesis stream throughput. And using KPL, do buffer all put requests as long as RecordMaxBufferedTime and on timeout pushed records to actual stream configured.

But here my concern is that if I go with KPL and instance is down before buffered messages pushed to actual stream? Will I lost all those messages or KPL do insert them in DynamoDB for later push?

Comment: you must be talking about [KPL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-kpl.html)  as you mentioned writing to stream. KCL is for consuming from stream.

Comment: Yes, corrected that. Thank you

Comment: I don't see the any documentation but I would assume, if its producer shutdown it would flush the events to stream before shutting down. But I checked their code, seems you have to manually trigger `flushSync` yourself before producer shutdown - https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/blob/master/java/amazon-kinesis-producer/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/producer/KinesisProducer.java#L760. **Now in case of VM hosting your producer crashed**, theoretically there should be something preserving those events in memory but I don't see that happening.